# How to model a pricing structure based on a > (greater than) or < (less than) operand

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-relationship

I have a contract table like so (extraneous data removed):

```
CREATE TABLE `contracts` (
  `id` INT(12),
  `serviceid` INT(10),
  `mode` CHAR(1),
  `months` TINYINT(3),
  `dateStart` INT(12),
  `dateEnd` INT(12),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Where the data may be something like this:

```
| id | serviceid | mode   | months  | dateStart  | dateEnd    |
| 1  | 111112    | active | 24      | 1319115600 | 1382274000 |
| 1  | 111113    | active | 6       | 1319115600 | 1382274000 |
| 1  | 111114    | active | 12      | 1319115600 | 1382274000 |
```

I would like to add a charge table that is based on the amount of time a user has been in contract, like so:

```
CREATE TABLE `new_charge` (
  `id` INT(10),
  `operator` VARCHAR(1),
  `contract_length` TINYINT(2),
  `amount` DECIMAL(5,2),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Where the data may be something like this:

```
| id | operator | contract_length  | amount |
| 1  | <        | 6                | 100    |
| 2  | >        | 6                | 50     |
```

Meaning, if contract length is <6 months, charge $100. If >6 months charge $50.

While, the modelling to me looks OK I can't seem to write a query that allows me to retrieve the charge amount without having to resorting to write an extra query.

Can anyone help me with either

- Using the given tables, generate one query to retrieve the amount
- Redesign the tables that allows me to generate one query to retrieve the amount

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a contract can go a hundred years, you still only need 1200 rows for this table. Personally, I would use CHECK() constraints on both columns, but MySQL doesn't support CHECK() constraints.

```
CREATE TABLE new_charge (
  contract_length_months integer not null,
  amount_usd DECIMAL(5,2),
  PRIMARY KEY (contract_length_months )
);

insert into new_charge values (1, 100);
insert into new_charge values (2, 100);
insert into new_charge values (3, 100);
insert into new_charge values (4, 100);
insert into new_charge values (5, 100);
insert into new_charge values (6, 100);
insert into new_charge values (7, 50);
insert into new_charge values (8, 50);
insert into new_charge values (9, 50);
insert into new_charge values (10, 50);
insert into new_charge values (11, 50);
insert into new_charge values (12, 50);
insert into new_charge values (13, 50);
insert into new_charge values (14, 50);
...

select c.*, nc.amount_usd
from contracts c
inner join new_charge nc on c.months = nc.contract_length_months
```

Comment: I guess i didn't mention anything about elegance in my question :) I suppose this would work but I'm sure it would break one rule of normalization

Comment: Have you implemented anything like this in real life before?

Comment: @superspace: What "rule" of normalization do you would that break? Single-column key and a single nonprime attribute--it's in at least 5NF.

Comment: In light of the fact there is no other takers, I'll have to award you the correct answer.

Comment: But it is quite inelegant. When it is inelegant my instinct says there has to be a better way. For example when updating `new_charge` with a new amount, numerous records have to be updated. This suggests there's duplication of data and that there may be grounds for normalization. Again, this is simply instinct, I'm not a normalization expert :)

Comment: First, you don't *have* to accept *any* answer. Second, instinct doesn't scale well. Mathematical principles underlie normalization. You can look them up on Wikipedia and apply them yourself. If you do that, you'll find that this table is in 6NF. Finally, "elegance" is in the eye of the beholder. One "elegant" feature of my solution is that you can prevent invalid data in the contracts.months column by setting a foreign key to this table. That means you can also get the data from it with a simple join. You can't do that with a table that requires every query to interpret inequality operators.

Comment: If it's not normalization, then i suspect it is something else :) The redundant records are what's troubling me. Given that the contract length is variable, I have to generate redundant records to ensure there's a matching join record. If I set a low bar (eg. 5 years) I have to continually check on this table, if I set a high bar (eg. 100 years), there's a helluva lot of redundant records.

Comment: If you use a foreign key, you don't have to "continually check the table". Once you've built it and controlled permissions, you never have to check it. The dbms will tell you when you try to use a contract period that's not in the table. (IMHO, that's elegant.)  None of the rows are redundant; each row expresses a simple and distinct fact.